# Log user actions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL 12+ is it possible to have a log with all actions performed by a user/role?

Eg: If that user executes a query, delete, create table, pg_dump, etc, store what he did in a log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set parameters per role:

```
ALTER ROLE user_to_log SET log_min_duration_statements = 0;
```